# Are PC games and expansion packs region locked?

Tags: pc, region-lock, battle-for-middle-earth

Title pretty much says it. If I have the US version of a game (physical disc media, *not* Games for Windows edition or Steam download) and get a UK edition of an expansion pack, will they work? Additionally, if I have the UK version, can I play against friends who have the US edition on a local network?

The specific question is regarding the Battle for Middle-Earth and the Rise of the Witch-King expansion pack, which are older games from 2006.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to region-lock PC games.  I'd be interested in knowing if that's possible at all.

Comment: I know certain Steam games are region-locked (at least that's what I've heard), but I didn't know about physical media

Comment: I know games are different prices in different regions for Steam, but I don't know of any way to lock games so that only those in that region can play them.

Comment: That's just what I've read...I have zero experience with Steam games. Maybe it was to do with server access only

Comment: It's definitely possible to region lock games - look at World of Warcraft initially, where EU versions could only connect to EU servers.  Whether any do so any more, or Battle for Middle-Earth in particular, I don't know.  I would imagine you'd be fine, but that's just an educated guess.

Comment: @dlanod: But even in that case, if you had an EU version imported you could play on the EU server. I know because I did that from Australia for quite a while back in BC

Comment: I'm not interested in connecting to servers (in any case, the servers for BFME2 have been shut down). The question is more about compatibility between the expansion packs, and whether I can play local games

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PC games in general are not region locked, as there is no native region locking mechanism for PCs. There are instances where online based games (for example World of Warcraft) are essentially region locked, in that specific versions of the game can only connect to servers located in specific regions (for example, EU game client can only log into EU game servers).

In the instance of LoTR: Battle for Middle-Earth/Rise of the Witch-King, the [Electronic Arts website](http://www.ea.com/lotr-the-battle-for-middle-earth-2?websso=1) does not indicate any kind of region restrictions, the game is available as a digital download and does not appear to be restricted to particular countries.

Comment: Thanks. I had already bought it and it worked, but your answer answered my question.